# GroupBy guarantees in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is GroupBy guaranteed to be safe to be "foreach'ed" both on the result and on the groups?

```
var groupResult = list.GroupBy();


if(guarantees == false) // want to remove this check
   if(groupResult==null)
      return;

foreach(var group in groupResult)
{
    if(guarantees == false)
        if(group==null || group.Count()==0)
           continue;

    foreach(var element in group)
    {

         //do something
    }
}
```

Is `GroupBy` result always guaranteed to be non-null and if any group is present in `GroupBy` can we assume the group to be non-empty?

In other words, can I assume `guarantees` to be always true?

Comment: what is guarantees?

Comment: the guarantees that I'm asking for. It's the pseudocode for assumptions to be true or false

Comment: the groupResult never be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `null` return value we can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach

Non-nullability is not mentioned directly, but as far as it's assumed that `GetEnumerator` should be called, it seems obvious that result will never be `null`.

We will have the same conclusion checking [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,796) — new object instance is created, which is literally non null.

And I can't imagine `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` to be empty, what the grouping `Key` should be in such case?

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit guarantees but by the convention all LINQ methods including `GroupBy` will always return non-null entries so the `null`-check can be safely omitted. Otherwise composability of queries would be broken and you'd see a lot of `null`-checks in the documentation too, e.g. in [Group query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results#example-1).

Each grouping result will also have at least one entry as otherwise it would be violating its contract.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check how many elements there is in a collection (group itself is a collection and also all groups in `groupResult` is a collection). So you can check whether there are elements or there aren't.

Take a look at below code:

```
if(groupResult.Count() > 0) { }
foreach (var group in groupResult)
    if(group.Count() > 0) { }
```

Combine it with checking for `null` values:

```
if(group != null && group.Count() > 0) { }
```

Here short-circuiting will guarantee if `group` is `null` then it won't check second condition which might throw an exception in this case.

Comment: it do not answer, short circuiting work also for `||` operator. I'm asking If I can safely ignore the "safety checks" when "foreaching"

Comment: @UberFace You never should omit safety checks, that's one of the best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by the definition of what a `group` means in this context a group must be both non-null and not empty, and the sequence (`IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`) of groups must be non-null.

Consider, where would a null group come from? A group must contain those items that are the same by whatever criteria is defined for matching. If nothing matches on a particular possible key, it must not be contained in the sequence of groups. It therefore cannot be null or empty, ipso facto.

Meanwhile, the actual result of `GroupBy` must have all of these groups, so while there might be 0 groups (if there was empty input) there cannot be `null` groups.

It is safe to remove both the null check and the emptiness check (there isn't a guarantee that the emptiness check wouldn't cost a requery, though that would be an unlikely implementation).

The emptiness check would always be safe to omit as `foreach` on an empty sequence's iterator would have just got a `false` from the first `MoveNext()` and so have not run the code within the `foreach` anyway.